# Possible to have a web style interface in a .net windows form app?

Tags: .net, windows-forms-designer

I'm about to develop a rich client desktop app. The last thing I want is the standard form controls, which are pretty boring, good for business apps, but boring for my target audience.

I'm proficient in web dev, so I was wondering if there was a way to use more web style custom controls in a .net app. I don't want to have to host a web browser control either because this will mean having to use JS to control clicks and stuff.

I'm really open to any suggestion that can give me a pretty / cool user interface, but must be done using ms technologies.

So what are my best options? I'vre heard of expression studio, is this what I should be using?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF is the way to go. The XAML screen definitions and styling have a web kind of feel, and you can totally go crazy on styling.

Comment: Well I had a look at WPF, and it looks completely awesome! I am sure the .net v4 version is mature enough to get into too. So I guess this has answered my question. I see you also have a choice to use Blend or not. Thanks Pieter!